# Nlog compatibility with .net micro framework

Tags: c#, nlog, .net-micro-framework

Is Nlog compatible with .NET Micro Framework?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation states:

- cross-platform support: .NET Framework, .NET Compact Framework and
  Mono (on Windows and Unix)

It does not list MF.